# Getting element with querySelectorAll() that starts with a certain string but does NOT end with a certain string

Tags: javascript, dom, webapi

The page I'm working on has many elements of similar elements, for all of them the id starts with the string "text_d" but half has an additional "_description" at the end. I want to add an event listener to all of these that do not end with description.

I know the startsWith and endsWith notations (^=,$=) and I've heard about not(), so I tried this:

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="text_d"]','*:not(*[id$="description"])');
```

But to no avail. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to resort to selecting them all and then sort out the unwanted ones out in the event listener function with something like

```
if(!element.id.endWith("_description")){...}
```

Comment: You have written two separate selectors there, separated by comma - but what you actually want, is _one_ selector, that applies both criteria: `[id^="text_d"]:not([id$="description"])` (The `*` is superfluous, because it just means “element with any arbitrary tag name”.)

Comment: Your querySelectorAll passes 2 arguments which is 2 separate identifiers. Usually if you want to exclude certain identifiers, you just do something like ('*[id^="text_d"]:not(identifer)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain :not selector to first argument:

```js
elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=text_d]:not([id*=description])');

elements.forEach(e=>e.style.color="red")
```

```html
<div id="text_d">1</div>
<div id="text_d">2</div>
<div id="text_d_description">not</div>
```

And your 2nd approach was good, its just not `endwith`, its `endsWith`:

```js
elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=text_d]');



elements.forEach(e=> !e.id.endsWith("_description") ? e.style.color="red" : null)
```

```html
<div id="text_d">1</div>
<div id="text_d">2</div>
<div id="text_d_description">not</div>
```

When you get console error * is not a function, always go check that * something.

Comment: Thank you! Excactly what I needed! As you said, the second approach works fine (I noticed the typo with the missing 's' myself), but I feel it's more elegant and maybe even a tiny bit better for performance if I don't select the unnecessary elements to begin with and thus have only half the items to loop over. Again thanks for the answer!

Comment: @viamonster Actually in this kind of cases you wont get any visible performance boost. Youd be fine doing both. It is more elegant way of doing it directly in CSS tho as you say. Cheers.